# Why isn't the RotateFlipType enumeration implemented differently?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, enums

Here is the declaration of the `RotateFlipType` enumeration from .NET 4:

```
public enum RotateFlipType
{
    Rotate180FlipXY = 0,
    RotateNoneFlipNone = 0,
    Rotate270FlipXY = 1,
    Rotate90FlipNone = 1,
    Rotate180FlipNone = 2,
    RotateNoneFlipXY = 2,
    Rotate270FlipNone = 3,
    Rotate90FlipXY = 3,
    Rotate180FlipY = 4,
    RotateNoneFlipX = 4,
    Rotate90FlipX = 5,
    Rotate270FlipY = 5,
    RotateNoneFlipY = 6,
    Rotate180FlipX = 6,
    Rotate90FlipY = 7,
    Rotate270FlipX = 7,
}
```

I understand how the values are paired together for operations that would otherwise have the same result. The above enumeration becomes unfriendly when comparing debugger values against `RotateFlipType.ToString` values. Also not good for data binding scenarios. For example:

```
var value = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone; // Debugger shows correct string for [value] which is [RotateNoneFlipNone].
var text = value.ToString(); // Output of [text] is [Rotate180FlipXY]. Presumably because it is declared first in the list.
```

Does this have anything to do with ordering of operations? Could they have not used `[Flags]` or split the enumeration into two (separating Rotation and Flipping)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize the horse is long gone, no need to close the barn door, but...

These constants were chosen in this pattern to make image reflections easier.

To flip horizontally, one can use this simple operation:

```
rotation_value ^= 4;
```

Vertical flip:

```
rotation_value ^= 6;
```

Flip both at the same time (180 degree rotation):

```
rotation_value ^= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a closer answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

Enums override the `ToString` method to use [`Enum.GetName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to find the name of the given value. And for `GetName`, MSDN has the following remark:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value, the
>   GetName method guarantees that it will return the name of **one of those**
>   enumeration members. However, it does not guarantee that it will
>   always return the name of the same enumeration member. As a result,
>   when multiple enumeration members have the same value, your
>   application code should never depend on the method returning a
>   particular member's name.

So, if multiple members have the same value, there is no guarantee that `ToString` will give you the original name.

Comment: Thanks. To keep binding simpler, I ended up using two separate enumerations for rotation and flipping along with a composite type to handle redundant combinations.